# How to uninstall zram from Raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspberry-pi-os

I installed zram from https://github.com/foundObjects/zram-swap but I am experiencing some lag issues.I cant find the command to remove it from Rpi.

Comment: Did you try the `--uninstall` option? `./install.sh --uninstall` (see https://github.com/foundObjects/zram-swap/blob/master/install.sh#L18)

Comment: Can you tell what exactly should I type in shell? I am new to Rpi and linux actually so don't understand configuration files well

Comment: Go to the directory where the download from github is located. Then type the command as quoted above: `./install.sh --uninstall`